# PLSQL results to Pivot Table

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I want to run a query in PLSQL to get the sum of sales qty in the data table within last six month duration and assigned it to the columns as month wise.

So far I did this code to select the data I wanted

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  (
    select 
      CATALOG_NO as PartNo, 
      to_char(INVOICE_DATE, 'MM') as tday, 
      sum(INVOICED_QTY) as qty 
    from 
      db.INV_ITEM_JOIN 
    WHERE 
      upper(CATALOG_GROUP) = upper('SPAM') 
      AND INVOICE_DATE between add_months(
        trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), 
        -6
      ) 
      and last_day(
        add_months(
          trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), 
          -1
        )
      ) 
    group by 
      to_char(INVOICE_DATE, 'MM'), 
      CATALOG_NO 
    order by 
      CATALOG_NO
  )
```

Then I get the results, and to create the PIVOT I have added this code after the select Query

```
PIVOT (
  SUM(qty) FOR TDAY IN (
    01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 
    12
  )
)
```

So once I add that It returns the table as `PartNo`, `01`,`02`,`03`,`04`,`05`,`06`,`07`,`08`,`09`,`10`,`11`,`12`
like wise.

But the data only goes to the `10` `11` `12` months only, Others are not filled. Can I get a help to solve this issue.

Comment: we should know the sample data set in order to be able to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TO_CHAR(INVOICE_DATE, 'MM')` outputs a zero-padded two-digit string so you either want to use:

```sql
PIVOT (
  SUM(qty) FOR TDAY IN (
    '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'
  )
)
```

Or, use `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM invoice_date)` instead of `TO_CHAR` and then you can use numeric values:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   (
  select CATALOG_NO as PartNo, 
         EXTRACT(MONTH FROM INVOICE_DATE) as tday, 
         sum(INVOICED_QTY) as qty 
  from   db.INV_ITEM_JOIN 
  WHERE  upper(CATALOG_GROUP) = 'SPAM'
  AND    INVOICE_DATE >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -6) 
  AND    INVOICE_DATE <  trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
  GROUP BY 
         EXTRACT(MONTH FROM INVOICE_DATE), 
         CATALOG_NO 
  order by 
         CATALOG_NO
)
PIVOT (
  SUM(qty) FOR TDAY IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
)
```

---

As an aside:

```sql
INVOICE_DATE between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -6) 
                 and last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1))
```

Will exclude values with a time component from 00:00:01 through 23:59:59 on the last day of the previous month. If you want to include the entire range then use:

```sql
AND    INVOICE_DATE >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -6) 
AND    INVOICE_DATE <  trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fb66df97cd09e61e56230be2f7d97ca3)*